# Change color of <tr> in datatable with color data pulled from database

Tags: jquery, datatables

There is two ways to display the sql data in [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net). The first is to build out an html table with a loop.  The second option is to use [sAjaxsource](http://www.datatables.net/ref#sAjaxsource).

Change the color of each `<tr>` with the first solution is trivial, as shown below:

```php
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>Customer Number</th>
    <th>WCODE</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <?php  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) :?>

    <tr style="background-color:<?=$row['COLOR']?>;" >
      <td ><?=$row['id']?></td>
      <td ><?=$row['customer_number']?></td>
      <td ><?=$row['WCODE']?></td>
    </tr>

  <? endwhile; ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

as you can see, $row['COLOR'] is the color of each row.

I would like to accomplish the same results using the second option [sAjaxsource](http://www.datatables.net/ref#sAjaxsource).  The `<tbody>` is empty and i cant control each tr. there is no tr.

any ideas?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use simple php, change:

```
<tr style="background-color:<?=$row['COLOR']?>;border:1px solid;" >
```

in

```
echo "<tr style=\"background-color:".$row['COLOR'].";border:1px solid;\" >";
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at their docs there doesn't seem to be a clean or easy way of doing this. `Note: I'm not familiar with this plugin. And I briefly skimmed their docs.`

I would suggest perhaps, although there is likely a better solution out there, in one of your cells returned(for each row) add an html tag like `<span class="SOMECLASS" style="background-color:YOURCOLOR; display: none;"></span>`.

After the table has been built and loaded run something like:

```
$('tr span.SOMECLASS').each(function() {
    $(this).parents('tr:first').css('background-color', $(this).css('background-color'));
});
```

However I'd also like to throw some opinion into the mix. Storing the color of UI stuff in the database isn't the best of practice, perhaps some post processing on the data should be done to determine if the row needs to be a certain color or not.

Hope this helps.

Comment: so if i want to add some static col its not possible with the ajax option.. right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by static column.

Comment: for example i want to add a col : EDIT and for each tr there <a href=t.php?id="+id (of the row)+"/>click</a> with the ajax i cant do that?

Comment: Sure you can, theres a few ways to go about it, just return the proper html as another item in the row, or build it up using jquery after. They have tonnes of examples up on their site: http://www.datatables.net/examples/